# Can I use different classloaders in my single Thread by invoking setContextClassLoader(cl) a number of times?

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

Can i set different classloaders through `setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader)` after Thread creation so that I may load file resources present in different filesystems during the various stages of my single Thread execution

The ClassLoader instances may have same parent ClassLoader but these different classloaders are peers to each other

```
public void run() {


    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader1);

    InputStream iStream1=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName1);

    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader2);

    InputStream iStream2=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName2);
```

Is it possible.Also please suggest if there is some alternate better way

Comment: I don't know, but if I wanted to know, I probably would start digging into the library source code to find out.

Comment: If u can suggest some alternate better way,it would be fine too

Comment: You can do what you have written, but there’s no sense in it. You can simply write `classLoader1.getResourceAsStream(fileName1);` and `classLoader2.getResourceAsStream(fileName2);` to achieve the same.